# Attach ControlsFX PopOver to parent node

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

Using a jdk 1.8.0 and ControlsFX 8.20.8 I am drawing a circle into a group that is within a pane and when the circle is clicked I want a PopOver to appear, showing details about the circle. All this works fine, but the PopOver seems to be totally detached from the entire application. The PopOver even stays on top of my workspace when I move the application to the background. When I minimize the application window the PopOver disappears along with it and when I un-minimize the application the PopOver appears in the lower right corner of the screen. When I drag the window it moves around kinda wobbly and doesn't really keep its position relative to the window.

What I actually want is for the PopOver to stay attached to the circle, which I assign as its parent in PopOver.show(). The behaviour is quite confusing, since it seems to be contradicting the documented behaviour for the PopOver, which actually says that it is supposed to stay attached to the window.

```
Circle marker = new Circle(panePosition.getX(), panePosition.getY(), 10, Color.GREEN);
PopOver popOver = new PopOver(technicalUnit);
marker.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
    if (popOver.isShowing())
    {
        popOver.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        popOver.show(marker);
    }
});
group.getChildren().add(marker);
```